# TIdFTP resumption TLS session of data connection

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

How to enable TLS session resumption of data connection with `TIdFTP`?

I am using Indy 10.6.2.0 that's shipped with Delphi 11.2 Embarcadero® RAD Studio 11 Version 28.0.46141.0937

**Edit 2023-04-12T06:41:35.496Z**

```
implementation

uses
  IdFTP, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdFTPCommon;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  ftp: TIdFTP;
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  ftp := TIdFTP.Create;
  try
    ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(ftp);
    ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    ftp.IOHandler := ssl;

    ftp.Host := 'myhost';
    ftp.Port := 21;
    ftp.Username := 'myuser';
    ftp.Password := 'mytopsecretpassword';
    ftp.Passive := true;
    ftp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    ftp.AUTHCmd := tAuthTLS;
    ftp.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;

    ftp.Connect;

    if ftp.Connected then begin
      ftp.Put('C:\temp\test1.dat', 'test1.dat');
      ftp.Put('C:\temp\test2.dat', 'test2.dat');
    end;

    ftp.Disconnect;
  finally
    ftp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I get still the message:

```
---------------------------
Ftpssessionresumption
---------------------------
Unable to build data connection: TLS session of data connection not resumed.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This is the log from FileZilla Server:

```
<Date> Info [Type] Message
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Response] 220-FileZilla Server 1.6.7
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Response] 220-Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Command] HOST myhost
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Response] 500 Wrong command.
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Command] AUTH TLS
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Response] 234 Using authentication type TLS.
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Command] USER myuser
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Response] 331 Please, specify the password.
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 [Command] PASS ****
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 230 Login successful.
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] FEAT
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 211-Features:
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 211 End
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] OPTS UTF8 ON
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] TYPE A
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 200 Type set to A
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] SYST
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla.
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] TYPE A
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 200 Type set to A
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] PBSZ 0
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 200 PBSZ=0
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] PROT P
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 200 Protection level set to P
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] PASV
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,24,198,132)
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Command] STOR test1.dat
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 150 About to start data transfer.
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Error] TLS session of data connection not resumed.
<12-04-2023 08:35:05> FTP Session 1438 192.168.10.82 myuser [Response] 425 Unable to build data connection: TLS session of data connection not resumed.
<12-04-2023 08:35:13> FTP Server [Status] Session 1438 ended gracefully.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indy does not natively support resuming of TLS sessions at this time (see [this ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/213)).

However, if:

- the command connection is protected by TLS
- and `TIdFTP.DataPortProtection` is set to `ftpdpsPrivate`
- and `TIdFTP.Passive` is `True` (but not `False`!)

Then `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` *should* copy the TLS session ID of the command connection into each new data connection TLS session.  That is the closest Indy comes to resuming sessions.

If you want to try enabling session reuse manually, you can use the `TIdFTP.OnDataChannelCreate` and `TIdFTP.OnDataChannelDestroy` events to access the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object of the current data connection. You will have to invoke the relevant OpenSSL session APIs to get the session ID from an old data connection and apply it to a new data connection.

You can use `SSL_SESSION_get_id()` to get the current ID of a TLS session (wrapped by `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLSocket.GetSessionID()`).  However, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` only supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2, but `SSL_SESSION_set1_id()` was not added until OpenSSL 1.1.0.  The above scenario uses `SSL_copy_session_id()` instead to copy a session ID from one TLS session to another, so that would not work to copy a session ID from one data connection to another, since there is only 1 data connection active at a time.

Comment: thanks for the info. for File Zilla Server, TLS session resumption is enabled by default and can no longer be disabled. one gets the message "TLS session of data connection not resumed". but it seems that this is not the only FTP server software that has made this mandatory. https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=54608

Comment: @complete_stranger well, as I said, as long as you are using Passive mode (outbound TCP) transfers, `TIdFTP` *should* be able to use session resumption.  It is only Active mode (inbound TCP) transfers that do not currently implement resumption at this time.

Comment: updated my question. do I miss something?